# How can I share storage file between two apps?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I want stored some file to can use between 2 apps in windows phone 8.1 (WinRT- Universal). Like use keychaninstore in ios or write to same file in same folder in storage as Android.

How i can do this?

Thanks for all support!

Comment: How big is your file? If it's small file, you can try to use *RoamingFolder*, otherwise think of some cloud storage like OneDrive or dedicated server.

Comment: I don't remember the exact quota for roaming folder right now (try to search over the internet) - it was probably something like 100kB.

Comment: Did you try using Sqlite ? You can convert the file to byte array and save it in a byte array column in a Table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way share files between two Windows Phone 8.1 apps. The functionality of shared folders (for apps from the same publisher) is coming in Windows 10. The best you can do now is to use OneDrive or some other online storage.

If you mean sharing a file between the same app on Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1, then use ApplicationData.RoamingFolder.